# Copying the last week data to the present week using php n mysql

Tags: php, mysql

in employees timeentry system each employee will enter the no of hours worked on a daily basis.To reduce the work i want to copy the last week time entries ie (from Mon - Fri) to the present week ie(mon-friday) 
I am able to fetch the last week data from my table as mentioned below

```
$query = "select * from table_name where (date(start_time) >= curdate() - INTERVAL    DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY AND date(start_time) < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY)";
```

Now i want to insert the data fetched from last week to be in the present week
lets for in this ie from(1july to 5july)
i am using php and mysql

plz suggest how do i insert for the present week

Answer (score 1):

if you want a simple insert of new rows with same values.

do this,
create the select query,
and create an insert query above it that will simply insert new rows and will add 7 days to the time reported.

something like this:

```
insert into `theTable`
select DATE_ADD(theHour, INTERVAL 7 DAYS)
from `theTable`
```

syntax may be wrong but this is the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add seven days to the dates in your `SELECT` query and `INSERT` them

Something like

```
INSERT INTO timeentry
SELECT employeeId, DATE_ADD(date(start_time), INTERVAL 7 DAY), --...
FROM timeentry
WHERE (date(start_time) >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY 
AND date(start_time) < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY)
```